Prevent local admin user to install applications
I have 2 local admin accounts. From one admin account, I want to prevent the other admin to be not able to install any new software. How can I do this?
What I am trying:
From the main Admin, Under MMC, I said group policy snap in. Under User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Installer, I can't find the group policy setting, "Turn off Windows Installer". What I see is this.
group policy
I see this option in the Computer Configuration, but I don't want to apply this restriction to the whole computer.
Or I am not sure if I have to do something in the regedit or in the secpol.msc, under application control policy, should I apply some rule. If so what rules should I apply. Please help.

You can't. What you do can be undone by the other admin. Admin accounts can do anything ...

Hmm I see. Because I found a way to disable access to gpedit, rededit for the other admin. I was thinking if I can do something in the regedit or group policy it would be great.

You may have found a way to disable it, but the other admin can use that same method you used to disable, to undo it, install it, and redo the change, and you would be puzzled on how they did it. As long as you are local admin, you can literally do everything locally, with no way to stop it. If the other admin is motivated enough, all they need to do is google the error message to get pushed into the direction of how it was blocked.

You can never ever block something from an admin. If the user is local admin, then the only way you can block something, is by making sure the rules applied are not local, eg. outside of where they have access.
For this, you need a server with a domain controller (active directory), but even then, there are ways to bypass it.
A better option is to simply revoke admin access and give read/write rights at places they need to so their programs keep working.
Usually, accounts are given access, because program x won't work without it. But if you give read/write fileaccess on the folder the program is installed in, this is often enough to not actually need admin access in the first place.
Another option is to simply tell those users they are not allowed to install the software, and apply some form of punishment if they do. For example, tell them that if they do install the software, you revoke their admin access.
